# one element must not be centered, as something does not look right

Tags: html, css, user-interface, alignment

I'm trying to make a webpage where everything is in the center 40% but the top heading does not appear to be centered with the hozrizontal navigation bar. See how there seems to be more space on the left than on the right, where the text goes longer than the navigation bar?

[image: screen shot]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sample test page</title>
<style>
#navigation li {
    font 34px Arial;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;

}

#navigation a {
    background: #140913;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 19px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    background: #4a3a4a;
    text-decoration: none;
}





#text {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#background {
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%

}

footer { 
    margin: auto; 
    text-align: center;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
  <div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">AAAAAAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BBBBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CCCCCCC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DDDDDDD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EEEEEEE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FFFFF</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GGGGGGG</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="background"> <br />
</div>
<div id="wordcloud">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit quisque malesuada erat sed sagittis gravida<br /> suspendisse in sem sed magna ultrices.</p>
</div>
<div id="wordclouddescription">
  <h2>The sentence will be aproximitely the same size here as on the final product, thankyou very much.</h2>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div id="text">  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you posted looks different from the actual result: http://jsfiddle.net/gnaowsxa/

Comment: @odedta Resize the browser to full screen. I had to say the same until I resized.

Comment: Well, he needs to specify his desired result...

Comment: @odedta the client just said "website should scale for different screen sizes" and wants large margins at the sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to reset your ul, it still has 40px padding.

```
#navigation ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on why the CSS to the navigation ul would cause problem to the left of the element beneath it?

Comment: Do you mean the child elements?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your'e starting from scratch and not limited by WordPress, a CMS, etc., start with a [reset stylesheet](http://cssreset.com/). I don't have the the freedom of just starting from scratch (my site's backend is ran by a vendor), but off the top of my head, I'd use:

```
    html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The html will follow a border-box sizing rules:

*Width and Height of an element is considered the element's rendered width and height.*

By default box-sizing is padding-box:

*Width and height + padding + border is considered the element's rendered width and height.*

So by default, a 200px div with 20px padding and a 1px border would have it's content rendered at 158px.
Border-box renders the same element so that the same div would have the element's content rendered at 200px.

The next rule `*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit;` makes the rest of the elements follow the border-box sizing but allows you the option to change any of the elements to content-box or padding-box if you need to do so (can't really think of a good reason to do so though.)

The rules `padding:0; margin:0;` are used on all of the elements because there a plethora of hidden default padding and margins imposed by browsers.

So using those rules make elements behave pretty much the way you expect them to for layout purposes. Read [this for a better explanation](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/box-sizing-secret-simple-css-layouts).

I made a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/epv629f6/) of your demo, and added the previously mentioned rules. I also changed the padding and margins of the nav and the #wordclouddescription so they look centered. I think that's what was what you wanted, I was not very sure since you didn't have a live demo.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to reset browser default styles. you can use reset.css from internet.

As of now you can use ul{padding:0px;} style which will fit your screen in center.
By default browser will take   "-webkit-padding-start: 40px;" style for ul element so, you need to remove that buy using this style **ul{padding:0px;}.**